# Casting ISO8601 date text to Timestamp

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver, postgresql-11

I'm working with some dates in ISO 8601 and when casting to timestamp I get some oddities in the millisecond:

```
SELECT '2020-05-15T19:01:59.002+00:00'::timestamp
2020-05-15 19:01:59:02 <--- wrong milliseconds

SELECT '2020-05-15T19:01:59.022+00:00'::timestamp
2020-05-15 19:01:59:22 <--- wrong milliseconds

SELECT '2020-05-15T19:01:59.22+00:00'::timestamp
2020-05-15 19:01:59:220 <--- ok, but I'm scared
```

I tried to use `to_timestamp()` but cant find a way to workaround the T in the string. Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: [It is working for me here in this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=81f848cc70fc4b56741825805ef07dd7).  I think the issue might be that you are not viewing the output in the expected format.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yep! Dbeaver was playing me tricks! Please answer. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I tested it in `psql` for postgres 13, and it is working correctly. Probably it should to work in Postgres 12 too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are seeing appears to just be an artifact in the view of whatever technology you are using to access Postgres.  As shown [in this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=96f51681995bfa2e049bdd4a385b94d1), in fact your cast to timestamp is working correctly.  Consider the following:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '2020-05-15T19:01:59.002+00:00'::timestamp AS ts
)

SELECT
    ts,
    EXTRACT(milliseconds FROM ts) AS millis
FROM yourTable;
```

The above query correctly generates 59,002 as being the number of milliseconds in the timestamp.